# reading files and relating information

Tags: python, list, text

I am given the following skeleton

```
#This function helps calculate each transactions and return the final balance
#PARAMETERS:
#filename: the file going to be read, e.g. "transactions.txt", type: string
#namelist: a list containing all company names, type: list
#orgBalance: stores original balance for each company, type: nested list
#url: the url you are trying to fetch, type: string
#RETURN: current balance information (after all transactions), type: nested list
def transaction(filename, namelist, orgBalance, url):

     #Call fetch(url) to get currency exchange information
     exchange_info= fetch(url)
     #Read each line from transactions.txt
     myFile = open(filename,'r')
     data=myFile.readlines()
     #Check which company is conducting transactions

     #If BUY, then convert the amount of foreign currency to USD
     #and subtract the calculated amount 

     #If SELL, then convert the amount of foreign currency to USD
     #and add the calculated amount 

     #Return current balance list
     #your list should look like 
     #[['Acer', 481242.74], ['Beko', 966071.86], ...]
```

and my data lists are as follows:

**transaction.txt**

```
Gerdau BUY Brazilian Real: 17454
Gerdau SELL Botswana Pula: 31162
Acer BUY Danish Krone: 61376
Equifax BUY Icelandic Krona: 41983
Acer BUY Sri Lankan Rupee: 91659
Datsun SELL Trinidadian Dollar: 71248
Haribo BUY Indonesian Rupiah: 41548
Datsun SELL Saudi Arabian Riyal: 71627
```

---

```
namelist=['Acer', 'Beko', 'Cemex', 'Datsun', 'Equifax', 'Gerdau', 'Haribo']
orgBalance=[['Acer', 481242.74], ['Beko', 966071.86], ['Cemex', 187242.16], ['Datsun', 748502.91], ['Equifax', 146517.59], ['Gerdau', 898579.89], ['Haribo', 265333.85]]
and the url=https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/jind/exchangerate.html
```

I am just wondering if someone can walk me through this, I get the first few parts but once I get to the third comment I'm lost. I'm not sure how to tackle figuring out which companies are buying or selling

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) applies here. SO is not a tutorial service, although you may find help on other sites.

Comment: The question here is unclear.

Comment: i know this site isnt about tutorials so i guess i should define a question, for the third comment in the code it says check which company is conduction business and so how would i go through the transaction text and figure out and sort which companies are buying and selling?

Comment: why do you keep talking about sorting, this problem really has nothing to do with sorting ... the `for line in data` of my answer goes through the file ... the action is BUY or SELL ...

Answer (score 0):

```
bank = dict(orgBalance)
for line in data:
    company,action,currency,ammount = line.split()
    do_something(company,action,currency,ammount,bank)
```

then you will need to write a function `do_something` that actually converts the currency to usd and then either adds or subtracts from the companies bank account

```
def find_currency_rate(currency):
    # locate the curency name in the text body and find the last <td></td> value in that row...
    return float(last_td_cell_of_row)

def convert_to_usd(currency,amount):
    currency_rate = find_currency_rate(currency)
    return amount*currency_rate

def do_something(company_name,action,currency_code,amount,bank):
    amount_in_usd = convert_to_usd(currency_code,amount)
    if action == "BUY":
       bank[company_name] = bank[company_name] - amount_in_usd
    else: # else we sell and add the funds to our bank
       bank[company_name] = bank[company_name] + amount_in_usd
```

Comment: i am mainly having trouble getting and sorting through information. so like i dont know how to go about getting the conversion rate like how to get that data from a list

Comment: I suspect that that is part of the lesson that you are supposed to be learning ... however if you would like a solution I can certainly add one

Comment: heres my problem, im a marketing major stuck in an upper level programming class, i think python is great and i understand how to write simple codes and wrote alot of my code up to this point i just have alot f difficulty with sorting data, i understand how to locate, open, and read a document and i know how to get it into a string and i could split the string up based on buy and sell but i dont know how to split it up so that the output would be the company name buying so and so that would be usable later. i dont know how to make it flow through so the the whole function works

Comment: yeah its rough ... I dont know how to explain it to you other than break it into small problems (like you have in the comments ...) Im not sure what you mean by sort since there is no requirement of sorting ... you just go over each line and add or subtract the amount indicated